# Matrix entered by user

Tags: python, matrix, random, user-input

I want to create a matrix of 3x3, with random entries (among 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) that the user is going to give (he'll have to press 'Enter' to start, but my code doesn't run. Here it is:

```
import math
line = ' '.join(map(str, range(4*4))) # Take input from user
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15'
items = map(int, line.split()) # convert str to int
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
3 = int(math.sqrt(len(items))) # len(items) should be n**2
4
matrix = [ items[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3) ]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: For one thing, split your code and output into different sections. For another, explain your problem more clearly. For example, none of the code you show actually has anything to do with user input or 3x3 matrices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line 6, `3 = int(math.sqrt(len(items))) # len(items) should be n**2`, you are trying to assign the result of the sqrt function to a literal 3. The sqrt function will do its job and you can store it in a variable but not assign it to another number like 4. If you want to compare the two, use an if statement. And if you remove that line, the code works just fine. Unless there was a reason for that line, then mention that reason.

Comment: Try answering the question and not commenting. This should go in the comments.